# Flutter http package does not exist

Tags: http, dart, flutter

normally the package should be imported like this:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
```

but now I get this error:

> [dart] Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:http/http.dart'.
>   [uri_does_not_exist]

did it somehow changed in the new updates of Flutter? if so, how can I perform a get request now?

Comment: if on vs code this might happen if your flutter project is in a sub-folder of the folder open in Code.and as you can see in comments restarting code or android studio solves the problem

Answer (score 122, accepted):

It is clear way to add http to flutter

1. Add this to your package's pubspec.yaml file:

> ```
> dependencies:
>   http: ^1.0.0 // latest one might change
> ```

2. Install it
   You can install packages from the command line:

with pub:

> `$ pub get`

with Flutter:

> `$ flutter packages get`

3. Import it
   Now in your Dart code, you can use:

> `import 'package:http/http.dart';`

**If you have done these 3 steps restart your code editor**

Comment: The part where you restart your code editor seems important. That is what worked for me.

Comment: Restarting Android Studio fixed the problem for me.

Comment: I don't know somehow ever after re-start it is not working for me.

Comment: That was also the case with me using Visual Studio Code. Add package to dependencies, restart studio then the problem went way.

Comment: This version might not resolve in modern versions of flutter. You can find the latest version number at https://pub.dev/packages/http/install

Answer (score 28):

Did you add it to `pubspec`?

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  http: 0.12.0
```

Comment: I up voted this because the example showed me how to add the dependency with proper indentation. Or at least I wasn't successful until I indented this way.

Comment: Thank you very much.. This was my problem. You helpt me a lot

Comment: awesome solution

Answer (score 12):

## In Android Studio import like this

1. Go to `pubspec.yaml`
2. Add dependency `http: ^0.12.0+2`
3. Click on **Packages get** at the top

[image]

## Few important things:

#### 1) Follow the proper **indentation** while adding the dependency.

> Correct:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  http: ^0.12.0+2
```

> Incorrect:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
    http: ^0.12.0+2
```

If you add dependency like this and hit **Packages get** then,
You will receive the error:

> Error on line 21, column 5 of pubspec.yaml: A dependency may only have one source.
>       sdk: flutter

#### 2) Finding package and latest dependency.

You can find the latest HTTP package [Here](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/http#-installing-tab-)
All the Dart packages are published on [Pubsite](https://pub.dartlang.org/) where you can find and see trending packages.
[image]

Answer (score 5):

Your code looks fine. However after reading the comments below Andrey's answer, you must also make sure that you run `flutter packages get` or `pub get` after adding the `http` dependency to your `pubspec.yaml`.

Comment: Did that too. that's not the issue.

Comment: Weird. Can you provide your `pubspec.yaml` here?

Comment: solved the issue. Restarted the IDE and the package worked fine. very weird.

Answer (score 5):

Add:

```
dependencies:
flutter:
sdk: flutter
http: ^0.12.0
```

to `pubspec.yaml`, update `Packages.get` and `Packages.upgrade`. If still not working restart the IDE.

Answer (score 5):

The answers here mention the package version. If you don't know the package version, but know the package name (as in your case), simply do:

```
flutter pub add <package_name>
```

Which, in your case translates to `flutter pub add http`.

This always fetches the latest package that you can use with your project.

Answer (score 4):

Add dependencies to pubspec like this.

```
dependencies:
  http: ^0.12.0
```

**** update packages get.

**** update dependencies.

Answer (score 4):

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  http: ^0.12.0
```

Answer (score 4):

First of all, simply restart your code editor
The caret ^ is not mandatory. You could add to your `pubspec.yaml`

```
dependencies:
  http: 0.12.0+2
```

`flutter packages get` is called automatically when you save the file if you are using VSCode or Android studio.

The problem for me was solved by restarting VSCode.

Answer (score 3):

Go to pubspec.yaml file . then add

http: any

below dependencies:

```
  dependencies:
    flutter:
    sdk: flutter

    cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
    http: any
```

then click Packages get

Comment: Works For me, simple.

Answer (score 2):

try adding the http dependencies before the flutter dependencies and click Packages get

```
dependencies:
  http: ^0.12.0
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
```

If you put after flutter that will make an error. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Clear the contents from .pub-cache folder located inside your flutter installation directory and then create a blank flutter project in android studio/ VS code and add http dependencies and click on "Packages get".

Notice that "http" package should be generated inside .pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org folder and then in your current project open pubspec.yaml file and click "Packages get", this trick should now resolve your "http" dependencies.

Note: Make sure your network is not blocking the downloads from Pub site and the current project is closed while adding "http" dependencies in another project.

Answer (score 0):

After doing all the steps provided by @Bawantha if the issue still persists then try the following steps this worked for me.

1. Restart your android studio.
2. Go to flutter Inspector toolbar
3. Click on refresh widget info button.[image]

Note: Make sure you have admin rights to do this.

Answer (score 0):

All existing answers say to add the `http` dependency to `pubspec.yaml`,
however that is no longer required.

I was getting this error for a different reason;
I was **getting this error in a library file**, which had the line, `part of my_library`.

**To fix it I needed to move the `import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;` line from my `part of my_library` file into my main `library my_library` file.**

Hopefully this is helpful to someone else.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eaMRG.png)

`dependencies:`
`flutter:`
`sdk: flutter`
 `cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2`
`http: ^0.13.5`

use this, you shoud not use space infront of *http: ^0.13.5*, use tab button for get alignment, and click pub_get, you should connect to internet first, good luck!